# ¿Quisiera crear funciones para sumas sucesivas y operaciones con interacción de dos columnas?

Tags: r, funciones, bucles

Un gusto saludarlos, recurro a ustedes a fin de que me puedan ayudar con unas funciones que no he podido resolver:
Tengo una base de datos muy extensas, solo aquí adjunto un encabezado, al cual llamaremos "a":

Caso 1:
si vamos al primer sujeto, lo que quiero es generar una nueva columna que trabaje con la "fech.p" correspondiente al primer sujeto que reste "2018-09-15" - "2017-05-21" ; "2017-05-21"- "2016-06-18"; "2016-06-18" - "2015-07-13" y así.

Caso 2:
Cambien si trabajamos con el primer sujeto; deseo realizar un conjunto de ecuaciones donde se trabaje con la "fech.p" y "dias". funcion es:
f= ´promedio(fecha1+fecha2) * promedio(dia1+dia2) + promedio(fecha2+fecha3)* promedio (dia2+dia3)+...

haya casos en que cada individuo tiene 1 o dos datos, como también hay casos con los que los individuos cuentan con hasta 12 datos .
Espero me puedan ayudar por favor, o recomendar algún escrito o bibliografia donde pueda resolver esos problemas específicos.

````
nombre=rep(c("YOLANDA","YOLITA"),times=c(4,2)),
Tiempo=c(1:4,1,2),fech.p=as.Date(c("2015-07-13","2016-06-18","2017-05-21","2018-09-15",
"2015-08-15","2016-09-02")),
fech.s=as.Date(c("2016-04-26","2017-04-19","2018-05-02",NA,"2016-07-06","2018-01-14")),
dias=c(25,40,79,120,60,92))```
````

Comment: Bienvenido Cruz Danny a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: El caso 1 mas o menos me queda claro, pero no entiendo el caso 2, ¿de dónde salen esas fechas y esos días? Por otro lado, es muy importante que adjuntes a tu pregunta lo que hayas intentado o investigado hasta ahora.